# How do specify latest point release in package.json

Tags: node.js, dependencies

Within a package.json file, how do I specify that I want the latest point release version of a module, event if I still have one of the same minor version?

For example, say I have a dependency on the module var, version 1.1. I have 1.1.0 installed in node_modules already, but the module revs to 1.1.1. How do I have it so that when I run `npm install` again, 1.1.1 replaces 1.1.0

would it be

`"bar": "1.1.X"`
`"bar": "~1.1.*"`
`"bar": "^1.1.*"`

or something else all together?

Comment: @sindre-sorhus, I tagged it with bower because this was actually affecting my bower.json file, rather than package.json. I just assumed package.json would be more well known. This is really a node-semver question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"bar": "latest"` in the `package.json` and when you want to update use `npm update`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clearer, but I don't want the latest, I want the latest point release. I don't want 1.2 if it is released. just 1.1.*

Answer (score 0):

Use `@latest` for the version

`npm install -S bar@latest`

Comment: So does that mean there is not a way to have packages upgrade with just npm install? Also, if this is the only way, is there a command to run this for all dependencies?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Take a look at this issue  as well https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3417